# Separate ListView Items with CheckBoxes events

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with a Choice Mode set to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE.
And Whenever I check, or uncheck the checkbox linked with each List item, the ListView's onClick event fires. I want to separate the two events, as when the user only checks the checkbox an event fires. And onClicking a list item, a different event takes place.

Answer (score 0):

And again...

Build a custom Adapter that uses your data...

> Whenever you want to do processing with the views in a ListView you
>   need to create a custom adapter that will handle your logic
>   implementation and pass that information to the views as necessary.

**Example**

http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/